# Passing parameters to freemarker macro dynamically

Tags: macros, freemarker

I have a macro in freemarker say

```
<#macro printHelloWorld var1 var2>  
    ${var1}  
    ${var2}  
</#macro>
```

When I call this macro as

```
<@macro printHelloWorld var1="hello" var2="world" />
```

It prints it in the expected manner
    hello
    world.

However, my problem is that I  want to pass this variable names dynamically. I receive the macro arguments dynamically from a source, 
and I want to be able to pass them on. Something along the lines of

```
$paramater1 = "var1"
$parameter2 = "var2"
$valueForParameter1 = "hello"
$valueForParameter2 = "world"

<@macro printHelloWorld paramater1=valueForParameter1 parameter2=valueForParameter2 />
```

which I want to be equivalent to the call

```
<@macro printHelloWorld var1="hello" var2="world" />
```

I have unable to find any solutions to it. Any tips ?

To describe the use-case more,

We actually have a freemarker macro, exposed via Java Tag which takes in dynamic attributes. I want to be able to call this macro, and provide the parameters to it dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

There's no language feature that does quite that. There are two possibilities that do something similar:

- One is simply passing an FTL hash (like a `Map`) to the macro, like `<@myMacro params={'a': 1, 'b': 2}/>`. In this case the parameter value expression can also be a `Map` dynamically created in Java.
- The other is defining a macro like `<#macro myMacro p1 p2 otherParams...>`, in which case `<@myMacro p1=11 p2=22 a=1 b=1/>` will pass in `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}` as `otherParams`. In this case, however, you can't pass in an externally constructed hash as `otherParams`.